# Moving an element to the front of a list in Scala

Tags: scala, data-structures, scala-collections

I was wondering if there is a way to find an element in a list and move it to the front of the list in Scala? Is there any easy way to do this other than iterating over the list, then removing that element and then pre-pending it to the front of the list?

Answer (score 10):

How about using `span`?:

```
def moveToFront[A](y: A, xs: List[A]): List[A] = {
  xs.span(_ != y) match {
    case (as, h::bs) => h :: as ++ bs
    case _           => xs
  }
}
```

Comment: this is better than my answer.

Comment: Instead of `y: A` as a parameter I would make it `p: A => Boolean`, which would make the method more useful

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of `partition` where multiple occurrences of the item of interest are moved to the head, like this,

```
implicit class RichList[A] (val a: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def toHead(e: A) = {
    val (l,r) = a.partition(_ != e)
    r ++ l
  }
}
```

Hence for example for `val l = List(1,2,3,3,4,5,3)` we have that

```
l.toHead(3)
res: List(3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5)

l.toHead(7)
res: List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3)
```